# How to highlight multiple search keywords using angularjs filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Once user get results rendered i want to highlight search keywords in results, when user search one keyword its highlighting but when multiple keywords being searched its still highlight only one search keyword.

How to highlight all search keywords using below filter.

filter.js

```
  angular.module('loggingApp').filter('trusted', function($sce) {
      return function(text, phrase) {

      console.log("phrase",phrase);
        if (phrase) {
          var data = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
          data = data.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        }

        text = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
     };
    });
```

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages | filter:searchStr" >
                    <td >{{item.filename}}</td>
                    <td class="serverResults"  ng-bind-html="item.value | trusted:searchStr">{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
```

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.$on('displaySearchResults',function(e,data){
        $scope.searchStr = data.searchStr;
        $scope.showMessages = data.messageObj;

    });
```

Data Text and Phrase

```
In below example i passed multiple strings ["3c72a612-4879-4877-b415-bf89ab110630","125981"] but it only highlight last one 125981.also from ctrl it sends one phrase `125981` as you see in phrase output from filter.

Text

[2017-06-16T02:48:36-04:00]zld00826infon/a[routes.event] ########## Message added to processing queue ########## 3c72a612-4879-4877-b415-bf89ab110630 { workerId: 6 pid: 125981 }

Phrase

125981
```

Comment: Looks to me like it should be working. (Tested RegExp in Chrome).

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs? (Text and Phrase).

Comment: @Arg0n i have added Data example please take a look .